# python convert timezone issue

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have Jalaali date and time as Iran timezone,what I want to do is convert them to Gregorian date and UTC time respectively and separately and then create a Django datetime object to save  it in my model ,everything works fine but when I try to save it , it saves previous value for them (before converting with astimezone),
but if remove the tzinfo from datetime object the save problem goes away 
this is my code:

```
import datetime
import pytz
gregorian_dict = {'gy':2018,'gm':2,'gd':3}
time_list = [9,0,0]
gregorian_date_iran_time = pytz.timezone('Iran').localize(datetime.datetime(gregorian_dict['gy'], gregorian_dict['gm'], gregorian_dict['gd'],time_list[0],time_list[1],time_list[2]))
gregorian_date_utc_time = gregorian_date_iran_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

so far everything is Okey
and the output is desired,
but when i try to save it the value for gregorian_date_iran_time is save instead eventhough the prints is desired values

```
suggestion = Suggest()
suggestion.request = online_request
suggestion.teacher = teacher
suggestion.session_length = length
print(gregorian_date_utc_time)
# 2018-02-03 05:30:00+00:00
suggestion.date = gregorian_date_utc_time
print(suggestion.date)
# 2018-02-03 05:30:00+00:00
suggestion.save()
```

but when i do this,i get correct result after save

```
gregorian_date_utc_time = gregorian_date_utc_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

I dont know if I am making a dumy mistake or forget something
what is the solution for this?

**edit**
looked up in database and find out that the value that stored in database is that the value saved in database is correct , but in django admin I get 9:00:00

> 2018-02-03 05:30:00.000000

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Django admin will use [current timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-current-time-zone) to render your Datetime fields, you should use [activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) to set the current time zone to the end user’s actual time zone.

Comment: that sounds true , django was exactly reversing my move
so I just let things to be the way they are and just converting date,tnks